# why dispatchqueue.global() still alive after deinit

Tags: swift, grand-central-dispatch

```
deinit {
    print("deinit")
}

DispatchQueue.global().async { [weak self] in
            
    while(true){
        print(self)
        print("sleep")
        sleep(1)
    }
}
```

Although `deinit` in class is called,
infinite loop in `DispatchQueue.global()` is still alive.

In that case, for example,

> Optional(<OutOfKiosk.DialogFlowPopUpController: 0x150116e00>)
>
> sleep
>
> Optional(<OutOfKiosk.DialogFlowPopUpController: 0x150116e00>)
>
> sleep
>
> **deinit**  (after deinit)
>
> nil
>
> sleep
>
> nil
>
> sleep
>
> ...(repeat)

I will really appreciate it if someone teach me why

Comment: If the reference count is zero, related class is deallocated from memory. Deinitializer is called immediately before a class instance is deallocated. As you print, when there is no reference to `self`, it is deinieted. But the code block in global queue, out of this scope, continues. You can break and return from scope if self is `nil` to stop execution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**DispatchQueue.global()** returns the global system queue.
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/dispatchqueue/2300077-global

GCD manages a shared thread pool, decides and adds blocks of code to global dispatch queue to execute it.

**In Debug Memory Graph, You can figure out many dispatch queues alive**
[image]

your execution executed on dispatch queue is not related to DialogFlowPopUpController instance's **deinit**

```
// your execution should not be completed because there are no break statement
{ [weak self] in
    while(true){
        print(self)
        print("sleep")
        sleep(1)
    }
}
```

**How about change your execution to break infinity loop**

```swift
DispatchQueue.global().async { [weak self] in
    while(self != nil){
        print(self)
        print("sleep")
        sleep(1)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The global dispatch queue is not "in" your app's class. It is "in" the system. You've launched an independent thread and it just keeps running until its operation is over, which in this case is never. That has nothing at all do with whether your class gets a `deinit` and the instance ceases to exist.

Indeed, a common mistake is launching an independent thread which, some time later, *refers to your instance*. If your instance has meanwhile had its `deinit` called, all sorts of terrible things can happen, ranging from a crash to keeping your instance alive in an indeterminate state after `deinit`.

However, that's not happening here; you have correctly used `weak self` so your instance has indeed gone out of existence in good order, as the `nil` tells you. So what you are seeing is the expected behavior, though obviously it's not a very good thing to do in real life.

Answer (score 2):

GCD manages the queues (and tasks dispatched to those queues) independent of your object’s life cycle.

FWIW, the fact that you’re using a global queue is not relevant to the question at hand. Using a custom dispatch queue (or an operation queue) results in the exact same behavior:

```
let queue = DispatchQueue(label: "private_queue")
queue.async { [weak self] in
    while true {
        print(self)
        print("sleep")
        sleep(1)
    }
}
```

Dispatched tasks, regardless of queue, with `while` loop will continue to execute unless you explicitly exit the loop (either with a `self == nil` test, or, if you want to manually cancel, with [`isCancelled`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/dispatchworkitem)).

GCD does not perform preemptive cancellations.

---

Note, it’s not even relevant that this dispatch task is currently running. It only matters whether the dispatched task has finished. The `while` loop is irrelevant. Consider:

```
let queue = DispatchQueue(label: "private_queue")
for i in 0 ..< 100 {
    queue.async { [weak self] in
        print("iteration \(i) queued by \(self)")
        Thread.sleep(forTimeInterval: 1)
    }
}
print("done dispatching")
```

This enqueues 100 tasks on that custom serial queue. But if `self` is deallocated before all of those tasks finish, this queue will continue to process these 100 dispatched tasks.

Bottom line, while we can talk about GCD’s management of the global queues, that’s not the salient issue. The key observations are:

- A task added to a dispatch queue (or an operation added to an operation queue) effectively keeps a strong reference to its respective queue;
- A dispatched work item (or operation) will continue to execute regardless of fact that the object that enqueued it may have been deallocated (unless, of course, you test whether `self == nil`); and
- Even if a dispatched task (or operation) has not yet started, it will remain in that queue until it finishes execution (or you manually cancel it) ... again, it is irrelevant whether the object that enqueued it has been deallocated or not.